# css grid, layout issue

Tags: css, html, angular, grid, css-grid

I have different grid wrappers as per below that create a css grid see also pictures. This works fine, however I have a hidden element "replyDev" that should show a Div element when I press a reply button. I want the element to appear below the Yellow element and it should be full width as well.
Right now as you can see on the attachment the purple area appears when I click on the reply button in the bottom right hand corner and the left side being filled with the green color of the "smallest wrapper".
Any idea how to fix this?

```html
.smallwrapper {
   
    background-color: pink;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 
    1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
  
    grid-template-areas:
    "uh uh uh uh uh uh uh uh sb"
    "sw sw sw sw sw sw sw sw sw"
    "rpd rpd rpd rpd rpd rpd rpd rpd rpd"
   }
   .smallestwrapper {

     grid-area: sw;
    background-color: green;
    display: grid;
   
    grid-template-columns: 
    1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto, auto;
  
    grid-template-areas:
   
    "td td td td td td td td td"
     "lw lw lw lw lw lw lw lw lw"

   }
   
   .lowerWrapper {
   background-color: yellow;
   grid-area: lw;
   display: grid;
  
  grid-template-columns: 
   20px 90px 15px 25px 50px 50px 50px 1fr 30px;
      grid-template-rows: 50px;
      grid-template-areas:
      "vb pm ua ua bu rd rp . fg"
      
}

  .tiniestWrapper {
  grid-area: rpd;

  grid-template-columns: 
  1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
  "rpdev rpdev rpdev rpdev rpdev rpdev"

}
  .replyDev {

   grid-area: rpdev;
   background-color: purple;
}

 <div class="smallwrapper">
 <div class="lowerWrapper">
 <div class="firstelement" </div> 
 <a class="second element" id="show"></a>
    
    

  </div>
  <div  class="tiniestWrapper">
  <div [hidden]="Boolean"
  "this div is the purple area and should    
  show below the yellow area as part of the green area"
  </div>  
  </div>
  </div> //small wrapper closing div
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you put your css and html file in snippet together?

Comment: yes hopefully this is better!

Comment: Your HTML has multiple syntax errors. It's hard to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issue, I had to put the div component one div lower. So that it is part of the Lower Wrapper.